# Prove that $(A-B)\cup (B-A)=(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that:

$(A-B)\cup (B-A)=(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$

My Attempt:

$x\in (A-B)\cup (B-A)$

so $x\in (A-B)\vee x\in (B-A)$

$(x\in A \wedge x\notin B)\vee (x\in B\wedge x\notin A)$

I suppose I should try different cases from here? I haven't been able to make progress after this step. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track. You could make two cases now based on your "or" statement.

Case $1$: $x \in A$ and $x\notin B$. Then obviously $x\notin A\cap B$.

Case $2$: $x \in B$ and $x\notin A$. Then again $x \notin A\cap B$.

In either case (that is, whether we start with $x\in A$ or $x\in B \equiv x \in A\cup B$) we know $x\notin A\cap B$ so $x\in (A \ \cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ and you can conclude that $$(A-B)\cup (B-A)\subseteq (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$$ Can you complete the second half of the proof?

Comment: Do you mean that I should prove:  x∉A∩Bx∉A∩B implies that x∈(A ∪B)∖(A∩B)  to make the proof complete?

Comment: @Physika No, to make the proof complete you need to establish the reverse subset relationship.  The direction of the proof you were going in only establishes that $(A-B)\cup (B-A)$ is a subset of $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$. "Double Containment" is the standard way to show two sets are equal

Comment: Oh oh, yes I see what you mean.  I can do that part. Thank you very much!